# Wondering what statistical test(s) to run on my particular geospatial data?

Tags: python, statistics, data-analysis, probability

I have a coding project I'm working on for school where you get to pick your topic and data etc. The data I picked seemed simple enough at first (and I liked it because the plotting itself was a nice challenge) -

I wanted to see if there was a correlation between ozone levels and the ethnic group of a household in my city. Basically I got census data that told me the numbers of households of different ethnic groups in a given census tract, so the ethnic groups are my columns and the census tracts are my rows.

Then I also found data for the average monthly ground ozone concentration in each census tract (so in this case there's just one number per census tract).

Now I'm stuck. I know how to code and make maps and charts, but I haven't ever taken a probability or stats class. Only calc up to calc 3.
My teacher is also a coder, not a statistician, so he wasn't sure what tests to run either - he suggested I google but google was no help; the class is mainly supposed to be about learning to plot geospatial data and then make charts about it, and the statistical test part is basically the last thing I need before I'm done. Google was no help and I'm in too many months into the project now to pick new data.

How do I find correlation between the two factors while also taking into account that there are overall different numbers of the different groups? And then the location aspect is confusing me? Since there are like a thousand census tracts in my data. I guess it would be a test where I just run it for each ethnic group? I genuinely don't know. Or some kind or probability test?

Any thoughts?

I haven't tried much since I am a complete beginner in stats/ data analysis/ probability. My only thought was that I needed to find the "relative exposure" for each group but I kept getting confused as to what that would even mean? Thinking of also posting this in math or stats stack exchange.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're right - as written, this question appears to be asking for general statistics/data science advice; it may more appropriate for Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Questions here need to be about a specific programming problem (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Stack%20Overflow%20only%20accepts%20certain,it%20will%20likely%20be%20closed.). Please adjust your question according to the recommendations at the link or it may be closed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some starting code to get you going. They should have explanations of when to run the statistical tests.

[This is a notebook with Census Data](https://github.com/thomasthaddeus/DSClub/blob/main/src/notebooks/census_variables.ipynb)

I have another more in depth analysis you could follow for more coding examples. But it sounds like you need to do regression analysis. Try going to [kaggle](https://kaggle.com) or [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) to research your question more thoroughly.